# Lightweight music player for Android with material design

Tags: android, music, gui

I want a music player app that

1. has [material design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html)
2. is lightweight, so that it takes up almost no memory when running

Optional:

1. notification of the playing song, which appears at the top position in the notification drawer

I am running android 4.2 jellybean

I won't mind if it doesn't have lots of features, only a music player with a equalizer (optional).

Comment: Specify the android version of your device

Comment: I'm running 4.2 jelly bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a little search on [Google play](http://play.google.com)  i found [Music player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musicplayer.player.mp3player.white), which is **material design** and  meet all the above needs , and is also very lightweight and fast.

along with these it also has some other features such as:

- Plays all audio files
- 5 band graphical equalizer with presets
- Bass and 3D effect
- MP3 editor support
- Play , next or previous playback by shake
- Sleep timer
- Color theme select option
- Plays song by folder
- Queue with play list reorder
- Support for play list
- Change album art
- Tag editor support
- Attractive widget and android 4.2 lock screen playback
- Library scan

[image]

Comment: Having tried this, I have to give it -1. Frequently crashes, bad to use.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [ACEMusic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/complete-material-design-acemusic-t2904994)

It's Light,Fast and Material
Some Features

> 1. Everything that a Music player must do(shuffle, repeat and everything else)
> 2. Unofficial Google Play Music support.
> 3. ID3v3 tag editing.
> 4. Custom libraries support.
> 5. Album artist sorting/tag support
> 6. Blacklist ability for artists, album artists, albums, songs, genres and playlists.
> 7. 9 band equalizer with bass boost, virtualizer, and reverb.
> 8. Individual EQ settings for each artist, album artist, album, song, genre, or playlist.
> 9. File/folder browsing.
> 10. Scrobbling.
> 11. Crossfade with customizable duration.
> 12. Auto-download album art from the internet.
> 13. 2 different base themes and 9 different color schemes.
> 14. Embedded lyrics player
> 15. Visual Animations
> 16. A-B Repeat
> 17. Much more!

[image]

Comment: I have tried ace music but I want something very light weight.

Comment: @Lnk So just try [nanomusic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.palefat.nanomusic_free) or [hikiplayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kazufukurou.hikiplayer&hl=en)

Comment: both of them doesn't seem to have material design

Answer (score 0):

How about [Phonograph](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kabouzeid.gramophone) - The installer's less than 5MB.

[image]

```
Material Design
The user interface matches every single detail of the material design guidelines to ensure Phonograph is an eye candy for you.

Easy to Use
No complicated or overblown menus but a familiar and clean interface.

Last.fm Integration
Phonograph automatically downloads additional information about your artists such as their images or biographies. When you install the official Last.fm app, scrobbling will work right out of the box too.

Dynamic Colors
The UI colors change dynamically to match the main contents base color.

Customizability
There is an inbuilt theme engine with many different colors to choose from.

Tag Editor
The tag editor allows you to easily edit the tags of your music files such as title, artist, album name (...) for single songs or whole albums. You can even either let Phonograph automatically download missing album covers for you (powered by Last.fm) or choose one from your internal storage.

And OF COURSE
- Phonograph has all standard features such as:
- Create and edit playlists
- Homescreen widget
- Lockscreen playback controls
```